# I would like to add ssl certificate to my already existing wordpress site

Tags: ssl

I have site named as www.splessons.com and it has 500 articles and now i would like to add ssl certificate to it. My doubt is does this effect to my old articles.

Doubts:

1) Does it effects to my old articles ?

2) Some of images have in articles like www.splessons.com/images/splessons.jpg what will happen after i add ssl to my site. I mean after adding ssl, https://www.splessons.com/images/splessons.jpg will work fine or not ?

3) Do i need to take any precautions ?

Thanks,

Hari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes it applies to your old articles.
2. There are several specific issues related to images which use **absolute urls** (mixed content errors). Basically you need to inform plugin/theme authors to update their code or to update it yourself (which is not recommended because in case of update you will lose the changes.)
3. Yes. After applying the certificate you need to check for mixed content errors and to fix them. They usually are connected to:

   - improper enqueueing of scripts and styles using absolute urls
   - using absolute urls in images, pages and etc.

[Here is a good article](https://css-tricks.com/moving-to-https-on-wordpress/) on how to apply SSL certificate and how to handle mixed content errors. **Remember to backup your website and database prior to applying the certificate!**